# Pass current object first Array as3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

Is it possible to pass an array whilst placing the currentTarget object first in the array?

I've searched online and only found reference to index, indexOf etc but no resources on how to do this anywhere.

I can send the array no problem but it's always as first loaded, through selecting a different object it must be possible to ammend the array or splice the new object to the beginning but would really be grateful of any assistance as to how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're asking, but you can use the [`Array::unShift(...args)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#unshift%28%29) method to insert an object at the beginning of an array.

---

Edit:
From your comment below, I think I get what you're saying. You can just swap the item you're looking for with the one at the beginning:

```
var index = array.indexOf(event.currentTarget);
array[index] = array[0];
array[0] = event.currentTarget;
```

or something similar to that anyways.

Comment: Thanks @JKillian, I thought that was only appropriate if the array is incomplete? ie by adding new objects. The array I have is formed and called into flash, I just want to be able to select an item from it and then send the array with the selected item at the beginning if that's any help.

Comment: Now that looks good. I was drawn into thinking it would be something like that but after many hours wrestling with the code which may or not have been half right, I deemed it better to enquire! Will put it to use and let you know but the logic seems sound on paper as it were. Thanks again.

Comment: Worked like a charm, haven't got the reputation on here yet to mark it up but +1 as soon as I can. There are something's with as3 that you need insights into learning, especially from people who have experience as there are so many ways and things to achieve a result that guidance helps eliminating the ways which lead you astray.

Many thanks @JKillian

Comment: No problem at all! And I agree, it always helps to be able to ask questions to someone who has experience. Doesn't matter that you can't upvote it, but you should click the checkmark next to the score to mark the answer as correct, so people know your question has been answered :)

Comment: Done. My bad, new on here and still learning! Everyday's a school day.

Comment: No worries at all - you'll get the hang of it! Always tricky getting a good understanding of a new environment